# Spark: Length of List Tuple

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

What is wrong with my code?

```
idAndNumbers = ((1,(1,2,3)))
irRDD = sc.parallelize(idAndNumbers)
irLengthRDD = irRDD.map(lambda x:x[1].length).collect()
```

Getting bunch of errors like:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.:org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 88.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 88.0 (TID 88, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
```

#### Edit

Full trace:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 88.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 88.0 (TID 88, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 101, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/bin/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 96, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/bin/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 236, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<ipython-input-79-ef1d5a130db5>", line 12, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

#### Edit 2:

Turns out it is indeed a nested tuple what I am dealing with like so : `((1,(1,2,3)))`

Comment: please give complete error msg

Comment: also, I think you are getting something like int object dos not support subscript, because of first item as 1. You needto make it a tuple like iandn= [(1,(1,2,3,4))]

Comment: true that, corrected it. was a typo I did in SO.

Comment: can you run your prog now?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> ian = [(1,(1,2,3))]
>>> p = sc.parallelize(ian)
>>> l = p.map(lambda x: len(x[1]))
>>> print l.collect()
```

[3]

You need to use len.Tuple does not have anything called length

Comment: I ran it without issue. can you kindly edit your question to add exactly what you ran

Comment: Turns out it is indeed a nested tuple what I am dealing with like so : `((1,(1,2,3)))`

Comment: Turns out, I did not have to use a MR here at all.

Answer (score 0):

agree with ayan guha, you can type help(len) to see the following information:

```
Help on built-in function len in module __builtin__:

len(...)
    len(object) -> integer

    Return the number of items of a sequence or mapping.
```